# Unity rotator script

Tags: c#, unity3d

I was playing around with Unity's new Entity Component System and I was trying to implement a rotator system.
This is what I came up with:

Component Data:

```
using Unity.Burst;
using Unity.Collections;
using Unity.Entities;
using Unity.Jobs;
using Unity.Mathematics;
using Unity.Transforms;

[GenerateAuthoringComponent]
public struct RotatorComponent : IComponentData
{
    public float3 radiansPerSecond;
}
```

System:

```
using Unity.Burst;
using Unity.Collections;
using Unity.Entities;
using Unity.Jobs;
using Unity.Mathematics;
using Unity.Transforms;

public class RotatorSystem : JobComponentSystem
{
    [BurstCompile]
    struct RotateJob : IJobForEach<Rotation, RotatorComponent>
    {
        public float DeltaTime;

        public void Execute(ref Rotation rotation, ref RotatorComponent rotator)
        {
            float3 rotationThisFrame = DeltaTime * rotator.radiansPerSecond;

            quaternion x = quaternion.AxisAngle(new float3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), rotationThisFrame.x);
            quaternion y = quaternion.AxisAngle(new float3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), rotationThisFrame.y);
            quaternion z = quaternion.AxisAngle(new float3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), rotationThisFrame.z);
            rotation.Value = math.mul(x, rotation.Value);
            rotation.Value = math.mul(y, rotation.Value);
            rotation.Value = math.mul(z, rotation.Value);
        }
    }

    protected override JobHandle OnUpdate(JobHandle inputDeps)
    {
        return new RotateJob { DeltaTime = Time.DeltaTime }.Schedule(this, inputDeps);
    }
}
```

However, I think that the code shown in the system is not verry efficient.
I am verry new to the new ECS stuff and I never did something with the new *Unity.Mathematics*. It would be nice if someone could show me whether the code shown in the system can be improved and if so how this would be possible.